# Show coresponding code line in valgrind (Clion) output

Tags: valgrind, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion

When analysing my code using valgrind (WSL) only output I get is list of problems found by it.
[image: My view (without interpretation)]
On the contrary in [Clion documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/memory-profiling-with-valgrind.html#explore-results) in valgrind section, images show that output (instruction pointer) can be directly interpreted into code line that has triggered it, as shown on the image below.
[image: CLion documentation]

Whan do I need to do to toggle on this display mode or at least code line which triggered it, I am using CLion 2022.2.4?

I have already tried playing with diffrent flags but I was unable to toggle this view on.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to this [bugzilla item](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=454925) (but not likely).

I tried it with CLion 2022.3.1 on FreeBSD 13.1. It was painful to get a project setup (clion didn't know where clangd or ninja were, and used a load of unrecognized clangd options).

After that no real problems.

I'm fairly certain none of the Valgrind devs uses WSL so the chances of this getting analyzed and fixed are very low.

Comment: I’ve requested a foss license from jetbrains. If I get one I’ll be able to test this myself.